# How to stop IE from caching my XHR

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['dt']))
    {
        echo 'a';
        die();
    }
?>
<div onclick="call('data_call.php?dt=a')">DATA</div>
<script>
function call(url)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        alert("");
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
```

If I run the above code in chrome (the latest version) and click the `div` it alerts `a`

If, without refreshing my window I edit the php file and change the `echo 'a'` to `echo 'b'` then save it and click the div, it alerts `b`.

The above is the expected behaivor. In the lastest version of internet explorer, for some reason it always alerts `a`.

Why please?

Comment: maybe IE takes a while if needs to be refresh before noticing the change in your code

Comment: @Arijit Mukherjee: it doesn't work

Comment: The URL is still the same, so what did you expect? If you don't want any caching you should make sure that every request is unique by appending a random number at the end, e.g. `&_=13141414124.123`.

Comment: To check if it is not caching issue, clear the browser cache before second request

Comment: After using the browser a bit everything is super speedy and the reloads are way too fast. This makes me believe m$ used so kind of cache in order to improve performance. But in my case it seems like the browser doesn't bother to request a new version of the php file despite the fact it should as I am requesting the file via HTTP GET.

Comment: @Jack: is this behavior IE only?

Comment: I wouldn't trust the caching setting of *any* browser tbh.

Comment: Is it a great idea to add the time or I should add a random number?

Comment: Typically the time in microseconds is enough ;-)

Comment: @BigBlue-san You can by adding &_t= (or any parameter you like) and adding the current timestamp (it's already past that timestamp at request end). Other sulotion is using php header expiry timestamps.

Comment: @BigBlue-san While this specific situation seems to occur in IE only, I have had the very same problem with Firefox, only for CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent caching issues (typically response headers should mitigate this to a certain degree), you're better off busting the cache yourself:

```
function getUniqueURL(url)
{
    return url + (url.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + '_=' + new Date().getTime();
}

xhr.open("GET", getUniqueURL(url), true);
```